# AWS Lambda becomes unresponsive after TypeError (Node.js 4.3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda with Node.js 4.3, and has DynamoDB get in the code:

```
dynamodb.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        callback("Error: DB problem");
    }
    else {
            callback(null, data.Item.someAttribute);
    }
});
```

I know that it's wrong, and I need to check that Item actually exists before accessing it. That's not the point now.

I get TypeError:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'someAttribute' of undefined**

Which is ok, when there is no such item, it fails. The problem that after that lambda became to be unresponsive, there are other healthy requests come to that lambda, and lambda just fails every time with timeout. 
As you can see in the logs below (from CloudWatch) even 40(!) minutes after the error, the lambda is still unresponsive. And I know nothing happens there, as in the beginning if the code I'm printing "Input to Lambda" which can be seen in first request. In all times out requests there is no such print, Lambda just became dead.

```
START RequestId: xxx Version: 1
2017-05-12T09:20:18.739Z    Input to Lambda: ...
2017-05-12T09:20:19.770Z    xxx TypeError: Cannot read property 'someAttribute' of undefined at ...
END RequestId: xxx
REPORT RequestId: xxx   Duration: 1094.61 ms    Billed Duration: 1100 ms
RequestId: xxx Process exited before completing request

START RequestId: xxx Version: 1
END RequestId: xxx
REPORT RequestId: xxx   Duration: 3002.12 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms
2017-05-12T09:24:08.556Z xxx Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

...

START RequestId: xxx Version: 1
END RequestId: xxx
REPORT RequestId: xxx   Duration: 3001.15 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms
2017-05-12T10:01:14.672Z xxx Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

Fixing the code and reuploading it to the Lambda makes it working, but how can this be that some error make the whole endpoint unresponsive. Waiting some hours also makes Lambda work again.
I'm thinking of removing "use strict", but it doesn't look like a good solution.
Any thoughts on what can be the reason to dead lambda and how to avoid this in future?

Comment: Are you returning any value from the lambda function? The timeouts usually happen when there is no response from the lambda function. Also, your timeout value seems to be 3 seconds. Did you try increasing the timeout value?

Comment: I know nothing happens there, as in the beginning of the code I'm printing "Input to Lambda" which can be seen in first request. In all timed out requests there is no such print, which mean it's just not responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there are many cases when Lambda becomes unresponsive, e.g.:

1. Parsing not valid json:

   ```
   exports.handler = function(event, context, callback)
   {
       var nonValidJson = "Not even Json";
       var jsonParse = JSON.parse(nonValidJson);
   ```
2. Accessing property of undefined variable:

   ```
   exports.handler = function(event, context, callback)
   {
       var emptyObject = {};
       var value = emptyObject.Item.Key;
   ```
3. Not closing mySql connection after accessing RDS leads to Lambda timeout and then it becomes non-responsive.

It's revealed that it's a bug, known by AWS team for almost a year:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=238434&tstart=0

Unfortunately it's still not fixed, after some tests it's revealed that in fact Lambda tries to restart (reload the container?), there is just not enough time. If you set the timeout to be 10s, after ~4s of execution time Lambda starts working, and then in next runs comes to behave normally. I've also tried playing with setting:

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

and putting all 'require' blocks inside handler, nothing really worked. The only way to prevent Lambda becoming dead is setting bigger timeout, 10s should be more than enough as a workaround protection against this bug.